# How do you crop multiple HTML paragraph tags to fit into an explicitly sized box with CSS3 or JavaScript (text-overflow, truncate, etc.)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, truncate

Given that you have an HTML div/section with a header, multiple paragraph tags (or anything block-level HTML tags markdown will produce, really -- h1-6, ul, ol, p, etc.), and perhaps a footer or some other content, how do you make the "content" fit nicely in that box?

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image: CSS Text Overflow]

The HTML structure is something like:

```
<section class='box'>
  <header>
    <h2 class='title'>A Title</h2>
  </header>
  <footer>[the image]</footer>
  <div class='content'>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    ...
    <p></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

I've tried setting `text-overflow: ellipsis` on the section, div, and p tags, but that doesn't work.  Is this possible?

Really just looking to see what is and is not possible here:

**Possible**

- You can definitely use jQuery to iterate through the content in the box, find the block element that's chopped off (top < box botton and bottom > box bottom) and truncate the text.  But, this is a last resort as it quickly becomes a performance problem with lots of boxes and all the different edge cases.
- You can create a "summary" blob of text on the server side that fits within the boxes dimensions.  But this doesn't work if you change the font-size or the size of the box.
- You can create a set of `font-size` and `line-height` rules that forces the text to at least be cropped in-between lines, but this is very brittle.
- Like @Madmartigan in the comments, you can also add a gradient at the bottom of the box to fade out the text.

**Not Possible**

- You can't set `text-overflow: ellipsis` in this case (at least from the things I've tried).

Comment: Why are you cutting off the text in the first place? I'm assuming you have a hardcoded height value set here? Are you providing a "More" link, and if so: does that link reveal the text or load a separate page?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397070/jquery-height-based-truncate-solution

Comment: yeah, you can read the whole thing by clicking on it, but there is no [more] link.  But one thing we don't want to do is create something like a "summary" blob of text (the server generates some string that's x number of characters for example).  So, assume for now that the whole article is loaded and just chopped off to fit into the box.  There's potentially 1000's of sizes of boxes so precomputing shortened `… [Read More]` strings server-side isn't viable.

Comment: This isn't what you want, but I've used overlays that sort of fade out the text at the bottom with a semi-transparent gradient. About 2em high or so. It's one way to handle it with just CSS, but I won't post it because it's kind of a garbage solution.

Comment: @Madmartigan definitely, we were thinking about that, that seems like the best workaround even though it's kinda a hack.  I'll add that to the possible list.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2646811/209139.

Comment: You've listed all the posible ways and have reservations with all of them. I think gradient is your best bet and actually would be preferred to cutting it off. It makes it obvious that there is more text, and looks visually pleasing.

Comment: @Madmartigan That's a worthy answer, you should post it. I'd upvote it.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff: I don't want to detract attention from this post with a shoddy workaround because I think the question is quite legit. Besides, OP already is aware of that cop-out.

Comment: I would recommend just one paragraph in your article preview with `text-overflow: ellipsis;` on the `<p>` element.

Comment: @Web_Designer: But that's the problem: Which one? You can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these 3 options on the containing `div.content` element:

1. Use `overflow:hidden`
2. Use a scrollbar - [jQuery slimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll)
3. Don't set a height property